How to detect when modified time (mtime) returned by stat/lstat cannot be trusted
stat returns the last modified time of a file, but I'm under the impression that it's not always updated correctly, e.g. due to the lazytime mount option or just the driver for some weird virtual or remote filesystem not implementing that properly.

Is my impression accurate or is mtime actually pretty reliable?
Is there some clever way to detect whether the returned mtime is meaningful in code, given that the user running that code does not have write access to the file nor to its directory?


AFAIK, the lazytime mount option means that, when the in-memory, cached copy of the file's inode's mtime is updated, the cached copy is not immediately flushed to disk, but kept for a sync, umount, or some other trigger.
When you ask for a file's mtime, you get the up-to-date, cached inode's mtime.
If you want the out-of-date, on-disk mtime, you'll have to do raw disk I/O, and parse the disk structure, find your way to the right disk block, and read it. To quote Chuck Berry, "Too Much Monkey Business".
